# How can I use Thymeleaf th:if to call javascript function without onclick?

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

I am building Login page with Spring boot and thymeleaf.
I pass the opcode using model attribute. And I want to use it for th:if to make condition to call javascript function automatically(meaning : without any click).
Here is my code under.

```
<a th:if="${opcode == 1}" th:href="'javascript:setlocation()'"></a>

<script>
    function setlocation(){
        var msg = alert('Loss of location information found. Turning into setting page...');
        location.href='/setlocation';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `th:if` on the script itself.  For example:

```
<script th:if="${opcode == 1}">
    alert('Loss of location information found. Turning into setting page...');
    location.href='/setlocation';
</script>
```

Comment: OMG so easy ? So <a> tag can be delete if I implement that right?

Comment: Yep, you can remove the `<a>` tag.